# Exposing a single field to users to create new nodes from a page

Tags: 7, forms

I am researching if Drupal is the right choice for my project and so far it seems like it fits, except for one issue. I want to give my users ability to create new nodes from a page, let's say it could be something like creating a Facebook status and would reside at /statuses.

Then these nodes could be visible to other users from the same /statuses page. I don't want my users to deal with publishing and path and all those other options that are available via general Create New Node form - I just want to expose one field that they can fill out on /statuses, hit Submit and then have Drupal do the rest.

Is Drupal suitable for such tasks and what would be the most Drupal way to do it?

I am fairly new to Drupal but have tons of experience with other CMSs and frameworks.

---

Edit

I am not looking to create specific feed Facebook/Twitter functionality - it was just an example. The functionality that I am going to create will include much more than that. Feeds were just an example - sorry if I gave the impression that it's what I want to make.

The question is what would be the most Drupal-way to expose a single form field that will allow users to create a new node from a page.

---

Edit

Here's a mockup of the form and page that I want to make. So what would be the best way to proceed?

[image: http://cl.ly/image/372p1f0Y1X3h]

Answer (score 1):

So you want to create something like simplistic Twitter/Facebook wall? Check following modules:

### Microblog

> Users can publish microblog updates, follow and be followed by other users, and reply to other users' microblog updates.
>
> Module also provides "public timeline" page as well as followers and following pages, and a block of "recent microblog updates."

Drupal 6 & 7: https://drupal.org/project/microblog

### Statuses (Social Microblog)

[image: Statuses (Social Microblog) module preview]

> Provides status updates / microblogs like Facebook's Wall / News Feed, Twitter's Timeline, and Yammer's Feed. Users can update their own status or write messages to other users, nodes, Organic Groups, taxonomy terms, or other entity types. @mentions and #hashtags are supported, as well as comments on status updates, viewing conversations between users, the ability to "like"/"reply" to/RT a message, automatic updates without page refreshing, and integration with over 20 modules.

For Drupal 6: https://drupal.org/project/facebook_status
For Drupal 7: https://drupal.org/project/statuses

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I gave the wrong impression on what I want to create - sorry about that. I am looking for the most Drupal-like-way to expose a single form field that would allow users to create a new node - see my edited question. Thank you.

Comment: @user11153 The status tags only work on statuses. I does not provide a text filter. So I have installed mentions module 7.x-2.x dev. I have created a mention successfully. I want to create hashtags functionality. This version allows to create other input filters as well, but I do not know how to use it to create hashtags. I also installed hashtags module, but it is not working on statuses form.

Answer (score 0):

You can create activity streams or Facebook-like statuses with the [Message module](http://drupal.org/project/message). Check it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I gave the wrong impression on what I want to create - sorry about that. I am looking for the most Drupal-like-way to expose a single form field that would allow users to create a new node - see my edited question. Thank you.

Comment: Is this what you have in mind? [node title field] [create button]

Comment: Yes, precisely.